# Open Modal Dialog after Modal Dialog close

Tags: modal-dialog

I need to have 2 modal dialog popup on Sharepoint site opening, but a problem is that you can have only one opened at a time, and the last opened wins closing opened before. So I thought that I need to open the second Modal Dialog only after the first one is closed by a user. I thought of something like fireing a OnClose event, that would call the second window, but have no idea how to do it.
Please advice how can this be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is 2013 (since there is no version noted)... You can have a dialog box open from another dialog box. That automatically closes the first one (technically, what I believe that it does, actually, is call the application page in question from within the frame of the original modal dialog; this would explain why you don't get behaviors such as auto-postbacks on that transition).

If you *really* need to actually fire it on the closing of the first box, you should just be able to call it from your callback function. See the signature here:

SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogOpen(url, options, callback, null);

The callback requires 2 arguments (I believe the SP-advised names for those are "result" and "value"), and you can use these to determine how the modal dialog was closed. I often use this callback to cause a postback but you could use it for anything JavaScript, really.

Comment: Thanks alot, SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogOpen(url, options, callback, null); worked just perfect.
BTW, it's SP 2010 Foundation.